# Could not find server in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

I have a new BizTalk server with SQL server locally, BizTalk creates a backup job by default

> Message
>       Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Could not find server 'BIZTALKSERVERSE' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7202).  The step failed.

The thing is that the localserver is up and thats the name of the current server, its not a linked server

Comment: Your code is probably trying to re-create the Linked server? Or there is already a Linked Server object called the same as your local server? Without code, it's hard to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting that message then for sure that server is not registered. to verify you can check

```
select * from sys.sysservers where srvname = 'BIZTALKSERVERSE'
```

To register you can check the below MSDN links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188717.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188231.aspx

Comment: but its the local server, why would I need to register the server as linked server if its local?

Comment: Your Sql code somewhere is accessing data located on that server , you have to register that server first.

Comment: How do you "register that server first"?